# How can I freeze Kotlin objects created in Swift?

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m using Kotlin-Native with native-mt coroutine support and the Ktor library.  I have several suspended functions that take in an object built using a builder pattern.  I understand I need to call the suspended function on the main/ui thread.  However, I can’t guarantee that the builder objects will be created on that thread.  My understanding is they would need to be frozen before sending them to the main thread to be called with the suspended function.  Is that correct?

For instance, this would fail because the query object hasn’t been frozen:

```
    func loadData() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let query = CustomerQuery().emails(value: ["customer@gmail.com"])
            self.fetchCustomersAndDoSomething(query: query)
        }
    }
    func fetchCustomersAndDoSomething(query: CustomerQuery) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mylibrary.getCustomers(query: query) { response, err in
                // do something with response
            }
        }
    }
```

If that’s true, am I correct that I would need to add a method to every such object in order to ‘freeze’ it, since the `freeze()` Kotlin function from `Freezing.kt` doesn’t seem to be accessible from the Swift code importing my library?  This is further complicated by the fact that freezing only applies to the iOS code, as the Android code doesn't need it.

Is there a simpler way to pass in Kotlin objects created by Swift to a suspended function, without requiring that those objects be created on the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

In the Kotlin/Native world, whenever you are sharing objects between threads you have to make sure they are frozen (immutable), if you are not planning on making them `@ThreadLocal`. Android is an exception, since JVM is not that strict, and let's you share mutable objects between threads.

You have two options:

1. Either expose a `freeze()` function and use that
2. `freeze()` every incoming object in your shared code

Also if you don't freeze, probably you'll bump into `IncorrectDereferenceException`, which means you are trying to share mutable/non-frozen state

Comment: For option 2, does that mean, practically speaking, I am unable to call suspended functions from Swift if they take in objects that I can't guarantee are frozen?

Answer (score 2):

You don't freeze Swift classes. If `CustomerQuery` is a Kotlin class, you would need to freeze that.

However, you only need to call suspend functions on the main thread if you rely on the auto-generated Objc interface from the Kotlin compiler. We generally recommend not doing that because you can't control the lifecycle, but that's a whole different discussion.

Comment: Yes I understand you wouldn't freeze Swift classes.  By the fact that the suspended function is taking in the object, it would have to be a Kotlin class.

What's the better alternative to using the objc interface when calling suspended functions from Swift?

Comment: Well, if `CustomerQuery` conformed to a Kotlin interface, you could pass that in. However, it seems like `CustomerQuery` is a Kotlin class, in which case it would need to be frozen and the answer from Nagy has more options. Alternative for suspend is to write a native interface that manages scope for coroutines. More work, but you can control lifecycle: https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/master/shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/co/touchlab/kampkit/NativeViewModel.kt

Comment: Okay thanks - that's what I was afraid of.